# How to placed collectionView in respective tableView Section

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have two collectionViews `CollectionViewCell` and `CollectionViewCellButton` that i want to place in first and second `section` of tableView respectively. I am debugging it by setting break point .

Here is my tableView.swift file `cellForRowAt indexPath`

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       
 if indexPath.section == 0{
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableviewcellid", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell {
           
            // Show SubCategory Title

            (colorsArray.objectsArray[indexPath.section] as! TableViewCellModel).headerButton.setTitle("View All",for: .normal)


            cell.category.text = (colorsArray.objectsArray[indexPath.section] as! TableViewCellModel).category
            cell.headerButton.setTitle("View All", for: .normal)
          // Pass the data to colletionview inside the tableviewcell

            // debugging...
                    
            let v1 = colorsArray.objectsArray[indexPath.section]
                    
            // what is v1?
            print(type(of: v1))
                    
            guard let thisTableCellModel = v1 as? TableViewCellModel else {
                fatalError("Expected a TableViewCellModel !!!")
            }
                    
            let v3 = thisTableCellModel.colors[indexPath.row]

            // what is v3?
            print("123Array=",type(of: v3))  // this is an Array, not a CollectionViewCellModel
                    
            guard let rowArray = v3 as? [CollectionViewCellModel] else {
                fatalError("Expected a [CollectionViewCellModel] !!!")
            }
                    
            // if we get here, we have properly unwrapped
            //  an array of CollectionViewCellModel
                    
            // so, don't make it an Array of Array
            //cell.updateCellWith(row: [rowArray])
            print("rowArray1=",type(of: rowArray))
            
            cell.updateCellWith(row: rowArray)
 
            
            cell.selectionStyle = .none

            return cell
       }
        }
    
else if indexPath.section == 1{
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableviewcellid", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell {
            
            (colorsArray.objectsArray[indexPath.section] as! TableViewCellModel).headerButton.setTitle("View All",for: .normal)


            cell.category.text = (colorsArray.objectsArray[indexPath.section] as! TableViewCellModel).category
            cell.headerButton.setTitle("View All", for: .normal)
          //  if let cell = ((colorsArray.objectsArray[indexPath.section] as! TableViewCellModel).colors as! CollectionViewCellModelButton)
            
            // debugging...
                    
            let v1 = colorsArray.objectsArray[indexPath.section]
                    
            // what is v1?
            print(type(of: v1))
                    
            guard let thisTableCellModel = v1 as? TableViewCellModel else {
                fatalError("Expected a TableViewCellModel !!!")
            }
                    
            let v3 = thisTableCellModel.colors[indexPath.row]

            // what is v3?
            print("123ArraynotNotmodel=",type(of: v3))  // this is an Array, not a CollectionViewCellModel
                    
            guard let rowArray = v3 as? [CollectionViewCellModelButton] else {
                fatalError("Expected a [CollectionViewCellModelButton] !!!")
            }
            
            print("rowArray2=",type(of: rowArray))

            
                    
            cell.updateCellWith(row: rowArray)   //break point
        }
    }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

Here is `updateCellWith` method that is called in each `section` of tableView

```
  func updateCellWith(row: [CollectionViewModel]) {
            self.rowWithColors = row
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

Here is TableViewCell.Swift file that has `cellForItemAt indexPath` for collectionView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0
        {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionviewcellid", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {
           // cell.imageView = UIImage(named: (rowWithColors?[indexPath.item].image)! )
          //  CollectionViewCellModel
            ///    [CollectionViewCellModelButton
            print("index1=",indexPath.section)
            cell.imageView.image = (self.rowWithColors?[indexPath.item] as! CollectionViewCellModel).imageView
            cell.dicountAmountLabel.text = (self.rowWithColors?[indexPath.item] as! CollectionViewCellModel).dicountAmountLabel
            cell.dicountLabel.text = (self.rowWithColors?[indexPath.item] as! CollectionViewCellModel).dicountLabel
            cell.customerTypeLabel.text = (self.rowWithColors?[indexPath.item] as! CollectionViewCellModel).customerTypeLabel
            
            cell.dicountAmountLabel.textColor = .white
            cell.dicountLabel.textColor = .white
            cell.customerTypeLabel.textColor = .white
            
            return cell
        }
        }
       else if indexPath.section == 1
        {
        print("index2=",indexPath.section)

        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionviewcellButtonid", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCellButton {
           // cell.imageView = UIImage(named: (rowWithColors2?[indexPath.item].image)! )
          //if let model = self.rowWithColors?[indexPath.item] as? CollectionViewCellModelButton {
                //model.collectionButton.setTitle(model.collectionButton, for: .normal)
            //cell.collectionButton.titleLabel?.text = (self.rowWithColors?[indexPath.item] as! CollectionViewCellModelButton).collectionButton.setTitle("Hi", for: .normal)
            cell.collectionButton.setTitle("Hi", for: .normal)
            //
            return cell
            }
       
           
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
```

On setting breakPoint in `cell.updateCellWith(row: rowArray)` in `indexPath.section == 1` of `cellForRowAt indexPath` of tableView.The debugger does not enter into `indexPath.section == 1` of collectionView function `cellForItemAt indexPath` it revisit  `indexPath.section == 0` of collectionView Just for both `section 0 and 1` of tableView `cellForRowAt indexPath`

It enter into `indexPath.section == 0` of collectionView function `cellForItemAt indexPath` and give run time error.How i can make it run `section  1` of  collectionView function on `section  1` of tableView.How display both CollectionView on View ?Just like in this figure

[image]

You can download the code from this [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18D-6XnJblPinR8MoELK3DJJeAG85hv0S/view?usp=sharing) run it for batter visualisation and see what is required

Comment: You have been adding the same question again and again since 2 days, Links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69605067/how-to-add-two-different-collectionviews-with-xibs-in-first-and-second-cell-of-t https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69616026/how-to-add-two-different-collectionviews-with-xibs-in-first-and-second-cell-of-t
Please do not add duplicating questions, if you are not getting the answer, refine your question add relevant data to help us debug, edit your question to make it concise

Comment: I have deleted them.and asked new one

Comment: check the answer I have added, if you find it useful consider accepting the answer by clicking on a tick mark right next to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code, answering or fixing all of them is really not in the scope of the question asked,
Ill only focus on the crash:

issue with your code is forced type casting. Error is fairly clear

[image]

Clearly you are holding array of `CollectionViewModel` (which is a protocol) and there are two different classes that confirms to this protocol `CollectionViewCellModel` and `CollectionViewCellModelButton`

and you blindly force cast both type to `CollectionViewCellModel` using

```
(self.rowWithColors?[indexPath.item] as! CollectionViewCellModel).imageView
```

Hence the crash.

**Whats the issue?**

There are way too many, I'll point out few relevant in this context. Your `collectionView` inside `TableViewCell` always receives an array of either `CollectionViewCellModel` or `CollectionViewCellModelButton` (One dimensional array)

In your code you hard code number of sections as 1

```
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
```

But strangely in your `cellForItemAt indexPath` you start checking `indexPath.section == 0` or `indexPath.section == 1`, how can `indexPath.section` ever be 1 if your number of sections is hardcoded as 1?

Much more strangely you try to type cast the element in array `rowWithColors` based on `indexPath.section`
In your code you typecast `(self.rowWithColors?[indexPath.item] as! CollectionViewCellModel)` if `indexPath.section == 0` and `self.rowWithColors?[indexPath.item] as! CollectionViewCellModelButton` if `indexPath.section == 1`

**What you need?**

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let collectionViewCellModel = self.rowWithColors?[indexPath.row] as? CollectionViewCellModel,
           let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionviewcellid", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {
            cell.imageView.image = collectionViewCellModel.imageView
            cell.dicountAmountLabel.text = collectionViewCellModel.dicountAmountLabel
            cell.dicountLabel.text = collectionViewCellModel.dicountLabel
            cell.customerTypeLabel.text = collectionViewCellModel.customerTypeLabel

            cell.dicountAmountLabel.textColor = .white
            cell.dicountLabel.textColor = .white
            cell.customerTypeLabel.textColor = .white
            return cell
        }
       if let collectionViewCellModelButton = self.rowWithColors?[indexPath.row] as? CollectionViewCellModelButton,
          let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionviewcellButtonid", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCellButton
        {
           //customise `CollectionViewCellButton` here with `collectionViewCellModelButton` data
           return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
```

**O/P:**

[image]

**TIP:**

Not sure why you have `cellForItemAtIndexPath` with incorrect signature again in the same file, its good that its not getting called, but it let me wondering why? My advice, delete it :)